# How can I change the Markdown of a post that was created using the "Ask Wizard"? It's formatted using 'heading' formatting

Tags: support, design, markdown, code-formatting, ask-wizard

Take a look at this (badly asked) question: [When I try to implement the project it fails and I get this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74964987/when-i-try-to-implement-the-project-it-fails-and-i-get-this-error)

I tried to change the Markdown of the question since the text is enlarged and in **bold**:
[image]

Typically, this text format would be done by using multiple pound signs, e.g. `###`.

So I tried to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74964987/edit) to post to remove the heading, however, I don't see anything special formatting applied to the text of the question; it's formatted in *plain text*.

I think this is because the question was asked using the "Ask Question Wizard".

**How can I edit a question that was wrongly formatted by the Ask Question Wizard?**

Comment: I sometimes wonder if they misspell on purpose. Is there some kind of perverse incentive (e.g., from other systems) for doing so? [Avoiding some filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem)? Or some kind of signaling? (Note that for the missing punctuation, [the original revision had (hard) newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4cf4e2a7-f099-40a5-9d4a-abb6f530a87c/view-source) (which don't render in Markdown).)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't wrongly formatted by the wizard; it contains a line of hyphens which causes the header formatting. When you remove it, the formatting will be better (but that grammar ... ouch ...)

[image]

Comment: Interesting, I never knew that you can format documents like that. For those wondering: I just checked on a Readmefile.md and the formatting is the same, so I guess it's meant to be formatted like that